# Problema al agregar un objeto a un arreglo en ES6 - this.listLogs.data[index].push is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6

Buen día, estoy intentando agregar un objeto a un array, les dejo el código para una mejor referencia. El problema es que me sale un error de que la función push no es la correcta. Quizá estoy haciendo algo de mala forma.
Por favor su ayuda o alguna pista de como realizar esto.

```
HTTP.post('getLogs', this.params).then(response => {
          this.listLogs = response.data
          this.listLogs.pages = parseInt(response.data.pages)
          return this.listLogs
        })
          .then(response => {
            for (const [index, log] of response.data.entries()) {
              const traceSender = {'idMail': log.id, 'currentPage': '1', 'registersInPage': '10'}
              // console.log(log.id)
              HTTP.post('getTraceSender', traceSender).then(response => {
                console.log(this.listLogs.data)
                this.listLogs.data[index].push({'senderTrace': response.data})
              })
            }
          })
          .catch(e => {
            this.errors.push(e)
            console.log(this.errors)
          })
```

Comment: ¿De que tipo de dato es listLog y la variable data?

Comment: es un objeto que almacena otros objetos que recibo un servicio

Comment: Si defines `this.listLogs` como `response.data`, en el `for` estás aplicando `Object.entries()`  sobre una propiedad anidada `data` dentro de lo que ya era la propiedad `data`? Como sea, `this.listLogs.data[index]` no es un array sino un objeto, por lo que debieras hacer `this.listLogs.data[index].senderTrace = response.data`. Y ojo, ponle distinto nombre a tus `response`, estás haciendo shadowing y eso se presta para errores

Comment: La solución que me diste funciono, pero al parecer this.listLogs no se esta actualizando y cuando intento mapearlo en el html me dice que las propiedades que intento referenciar no existen, pero cuando veo el objeto en la consola si se visualizan. Que puede estar pasando. Estoy usando Vue.js 2. Gracias.